# Node Js User Management

Tags: node.js, authentication

I have an app developed using node js. No servers,No install, No trace, No database. However I would like to integrate a user sign up and authentication scheme into this app. First I know I will need to get the information the user sign up with to be able to log them in and I know how to accomplish this traditionally using a database. What I want to know is if I can achieve user sign up and log in using node js without the idea of a database. Please point me in the right direction. I am new to node js.

Comment: Where do you intend to store the usernames and credentials if you're not using a database? In memory? On the filesystem?

Comment: I am thinking File system. Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Redis` could help you out, it allows you to store key/values in memory, including hashes.

> Redis is an open source, BSD licensed, advanced key-value store... Redis works with an in-memory dataset.

http://redis.io/

Answer (score 2):

There're several Node.js modules/applications for user management:

- [Passport](http://passportjs.org/)
- Mongoose + [Auth module](https://github.com/bnoguchi/mongoose-auth)
- [Drywall](http://jedireza.github.io/drywall/)

I highly recommend the first one - Passport. It is easily integrated, extendable and stable authentication solution.

Comment: Thanks. So these modules don't require any server side / DB programming?